# JavaScript: Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, methods, undefined

Hello stackoverflow members. 
I´m deploying following piece of code into my parse cloud. The code works fine as long as the marked area is not in it.

Why am i getting the error: cannot call method ´get´ of undefined, only when i put constraints in my query? The error happens in line 24. And like i said, if there is no constraints, the method get works.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUserLookingForChat", function(request, response) {
    var remote_id_searcher = request.params.username;
    var private_name_searcher = request.params.private_name;
    var intentions_searcher = request.params.intentions;
    var gender_searcher = request.params.gender;
    var looking_gender_searcher = request.params.lookinggender;

    var query = new Parse.Query("userLookingForChat");
```

//WITHOUT THIS PIECE IT WORKS

```
    /*query.equalTo("gender", looking_gender_searcher); 
    query.equalTo("lookinggender", gender_searcher); 
    if(intentions_searcher === "date"){
        query.notcontainedIn("intentions", "friends");
    }
    if(intentions_searcher === "friends"){
        query.notcontainedIn("intentions", "date");
    }*/
```

//**__**

```
    query.first({
   success: function(user) {  

       response.success(user);

       Parse.Push.send({
              channels: [user.get("username")],
              data: {
                 action: "com.example.ACCEPT_INVENTATION", 
                remote_id_partner: remote_id_searcher,
                private_name: private_name_searcher,
                age: "20"

              }
            });

        user.destroy({
         success:function() {
              response.success(message);
         },
         error:function(error) {
              response.error("Could not delete object.");
         }
    });

   },
   error: function() {
     response.error("no user is currently looking for a chat");
   }
 });
});
```

Thanks for your help already.

Comment: Are you sure that neither "gender_searcher" or "looking_gender_searcher" cannot be null or undefined?

Comment: I just checked. They are never null. I will put a try catch around it tho. 
What else could be the reason?

It just seemd like, the second im putting constraints in my query, java script doesn´t know that its returning a parse.object anymore